# Im making game like the binding of isaac but i dont know how to move image with wsad python 3.10.4 pygame. I tried

Tags: python, pygame

Image is matiskinfinal.png
I make a grid cuz i think i can do easliy border than if i havent it
i delete imports and less important code
I tried to create a variable and add to it and then add this variable to x or y but it doesn't work

thanks for help

```
screen_width = 1530
screen_height = 780
pygame.display.set_caption("Kroniki Matiego")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1530,780))


skin = pygame.image.load('matiskinfinal.png')


def add_skin_at_location(x,y):
    screen.blit(skin,(x,y))
x = 726
y = 390
add_skin_at_location(x, y)

#skin

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
delta = 0.0

#grid

def drawGrid():
    blockSize = 111 #Set the size of the grid block
    for x in range(0, screen_width, blockSize):
        for y in range(0, screen_height, blockSize):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, rect, 1)

while True:
        drawGrid()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        pygame.display.update()

skin = pygame.image.load('matiskin.png')
    drawGrid()
    #Ticking
    delta += clock.tick()/1000.0
    while delta > 1 / max_tps:
          delta -= 1/max_tps
          # Checking imputs
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        x_change += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        y_change += 1
    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        y_change -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        x_change -= 1
```